# Expected number of tail before $T_M$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

> We flip a coin with head probability $p$. Before the game starts, we have 1 dollars. Each time we flip the coin, if it's head, then our fortune increases by 1; if it's tail, then our fortune returns to 1. Let $S_i$ be our fortune at $i$-th trial (so $S_0 = 1$).
>
> Let $T_M = \min\left\{i: S_i = M \right\}$. Find the expected value of tails before $T_M$, $\mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{i=1}^{T_M} 1_{Tail}\right]$

I tried to use Wald's identity since $T_M$ is a stopping time, but I still need to find $\mathbb{E}\left[T_M\right]$. I'm not sure how to find it. My vague thought is to use geometric random variable, with the event "getting $M-1$ heads in row" as success (having probability $p^{M-1}$), but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672956/stopping-time-on-an-asymmetric-random-walk

Comment: @d.k.o. In this problem, tails returns you back to 1, so this is not a random walk.

Comment: @d.k.o. In asymmetric random walk, the sum either goes up or down by 1. (So, if I have 5 mesos at time $i$, I would now have 4 or 6 mesos.) Here, tails takes you back to 1. (So, I either have 6 mesos or one meso)

Comment: @E.A. Oh, I misread the question!

Comment: Also OP, yes, your intuition should work; you will have success after on average $p^{-(M-1)}$ streaks of heads, and number of expected trials is precisely the number of tails you have.

Comment: @E-A My main confusion is are the events "getting $M-1$ heads in a row starting from $i$-th trial" independent? For example, if "getting $M-1$ heads in a row starting from $1$-st trial" happens, then trial 2 through $M-1$ are all heads, which increases the probability of "getting $M-1$ heads in a row starting from $2$-nd trial"

Comment: @3x89g2 I guess I did not clarify what I meant by a trial: I meant as a "trial" a sequence of heads followed by a tail, or 50 heads. Once you toss the tail, you start a new "trial". Now, each of these trials are independent with success probability $p^{(M-1)}$ (so like you said it is geometric). Number of tails will be one less than the number of trials (since last trial does not have a tail at the end) and the result follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It requires $M-1$ consecutive heads to stop. The expected number of steps until $M-1$ consecutive heads is given by
$$
\mathsf{E}T_M=\frac{p^{-M+1}-1}{1-p}.
$$

Then the **expected number of tails** is $(1-p)\mathsf{E}T_M=p^{-M+1}-1$.

Comment: But the correct answer is $\frac{1 - p^{M-1}}{p^{M-1}}$

Comment: @3x89g2 Indeed,
$$
\frac{1-p^{M-1}}{p^{M-1}}=p^{-M+1}-1.
$$

Comment: Sorry. I meant, how do we get $E T_M$? Why $\frac{p^{-M+1} - 1}{1-p}$?

Comment: @3x89g2 If $E_n$ is the average number of steps until the first run of $n$ heads, then it satisfies the following relation:
\begin{align}
E_n&=(1-p)(1+E_n)+p(1-p)(2+E_n)+\cdots+p^nn \\
&=E_n-p^nE_n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}p^k.
\end{align}
So
$$
E_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{p^k}{p^n}=\frac{p^{-n}-1}{1-p}.
$$